# Trying to get Geolocation, "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null"?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

```
var lat = document.querySelector("#lat");
var long = document.querySelector("#long")
var latLong = document.getElementById("latLong");

if (navigator.geolocation){
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(myPosition)
}
else {
  latLong.innerHTML = "sorry, position not avaliable"
}

function myPosition (position){
  lat.value  =  position.coords.latitude;
  long.value = position.coords.longitude;
}
```

Not really sure what's going on here/why it's giving me this  error.
If I change myPosition to

```
function myPosition (position){
      latLong.innerHTML =  "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude  + 
      "Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
    }
```

It works completely fine, with no error.  But I want my latitude and longitude each in separate variables

Am I missing something these? I cannot understand why this is not working. I've tried lat.textContent/long.textContent, lat.innerHTML/long.innerHTML and nothing seems to work for each individual coordinate

HTML:

```
<h2> Your location is... </h2>

<div id="latLong"></div>

<div id="lag">Latitude: </div>
<div id="long">Longitude: </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML? You might have mistyped a selector

Comment: @CertainPerformance edited, sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

You mistyped the ID of an element in your HTML.

```
<div id="lag">Latitude: </div>
```

should be

```
<div id="lat">Latitude: </div>
```

if you want to select it with `#lat`. Then your myPosition which assigns to separate elements won't error out.

However, you should only use `.value` when assigning *input values*, such as to input fields and textareas. Otherwise, if you want to set the text content of a `div` or some other element, use `.textContent`:

```
function myPosition (position){
  lat.textContent  = position.coords.latitude;
  long.textContent = position.coords.longitude;
}
```

Comment: Ah got it. Well it should be working now, but I cannot get my location to show on chrome. Maybe its something on chromes part, because it is not showing any error in the console. Tried on several computers, local file as well as codepen, nothing showing. Something on google side I'm assuming ?

Comment: Your warnings might be hidden. I see this message: `Geolocation access has been blocked because of a Feature Policy applied to the current document. See https://goo .gl/EuHzyv for more details.`. It has to do with the page the script is used on, along with browser permissions, I think.